# Modify Magento2 module php class

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, class

I have to add a work around fix for a payment method by adding a line of code to `vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php`.

I've tried my fix by adding it directly to **that** file and it's working, but since files in the vendor folder shouldn't be modified, I'll have to put that fix in `app/code`.

I've tried adding a copy of the file along with my modified code in `app/code/Magento/Payment/Helper/Data.php` instead. Nothing happens and the bug is still there and I can't find any documentation on this.

How do I override that specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a specific class one should use Dependency Injection.

More specifically di.xml and the preference node.

Examples and docs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html
http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/22/preferences-in-magento-2/

Another good explication can be found here
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences/

Answer (score 1):

Create your own module and add below code to,

> app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Helper\Data" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Payment\Data" />
</config>
```

Now create your helper file `Data.php` under below location,

> app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/Helper/Payment/Data.php

And the below code to Data.php

```
<?php

namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Payment;

class Data extends \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
{    
    ...Your Code...
}
?>
```

Now add your modified code to that file.